# Como obter a soma de três tabelas no sql

Tags: mysql, sql, mysqli

Possuo 3 Tabelas, sendo elas:

- Escola: `id`, `id_escola` e `nome_escola`;
- Professor: `id`, `id_escola` e `nome_professor`;
- Alunos: `id`, `id_escola`, `sala_aula` e `numero_alunos`;

Tenho conhecimento dos `joins`, `count`'s, e `sum`'s porém não estou conseguindo montar o `SQL`.

Eu preciso retornar uma linha de uma escola específica com o nome da escola, quantidade de alunos, quantidade de salas e a quantidade de professores.

Como montar essa query ?

Answer (score 1):

Tenta essa consulta.
Mas assim... você pode melhorar a estrutura da suas tabelas.

A tabela **escola** não precisa de duas chaves primárias a não ser que seja necessário.

Na tabela **alunos** não precisa da coluna `numero_alunos`.

```
SELECT 
    NOME_ESCOLA,
    NOME_PROFESSOR,
    COUNT(ALUNOS.ID) AS TOTAL_ALUNOS
FROM
    ESCOLA
INNER JOIN
    PROFESSOR ON PROFESSOR.ID_ESCOLA = ESCOLA.ID_ESCOLA
INNER JOIN
    ALUNOS ON ALUNOS.ID_ESCOLA = ESCOLA.ID_ESCOLA
GROUP BY 
    NOME_ESCOLA, NOME_PROFESSOR
```

Answer (score 1):

Caso não seja do seu interesse alterar o modelo de dados, com *subqueries* funciona assim:

```
SELECT
    e.nome_escola,
    (SELECT COUNT(p.id) FROM Professor p WHERE p.id_escola = e.id) AS professors_count,
    (SELECT COUNT(a.id) FROM Alunos a1 WHERE a1.id_escola = e.id) AS students_count,
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT a2.sala_aula) FROM Alunos a2 WHERE a2.id_escola = e.id) AS rooms_count,
FROM Escola e;
```